# What does the wakeup tab actually do on Powertop in Linux?

Tags: linux, powertop

What does the wakeup tab actually do on Powertop in Linux?

I tried experimenting a bit with alternating the states, between enabled and disabled, and couldn't figure it out.

[image]

edit: i did try reading through the man and searching and asking AI.

Comment: I would imagine that when set to Enabled for a device that is currently turned off, it would start transmitting a wake on lan packet to said device, and possibly set itself to disabled once it confirms that the device woke up.

Comment: A suggestion: the Title of the post should not be the question, or, at least, should not be the only place the question exists in your post. Right now, your post is "I tried experimenting with alternating the status and couldn't figure it out." What states, in what system, how, why? Titles tell you about the post, they're about attracting attention more than being the only relevant information in the post.

Comment: @music2myear The question was already tagged as linux.

Comment: @LPChip thank you. You think its the same even for the devices that don't specify LAN?

Comment: Linux is pretty broad, and PowerTop is already a Linux utility. Which flavor/variant of Linux are you referring to? What are the details of your hardware that PowerTop may be able to integrate with? There are documentation sites already listing what PowerTop does and how it works. Which of these have you reviewed, have you tried what they describe, and what was the outcome?

Comment: @gl00ten I have no idea. I don't have experience with this program, its just that it seems to be the most obvious feature considered all the other information on the screenshot. I don't know for sure if it does this, but I do think this is what it would do. Maybe there's a manual somewhere that explains it in more detail?

Comment: @LPChip Thank you. I did try looking for info on the man, and online but couldn't find anything. If no one can help here, next step will be to email the maintainer.

Comment: One other thing this could be is changing a device parameter to tell the OS if that device can wake the system up or not. Wakeup on LAN requires a WoL packet to be received, USB device would mean, you use it and it wakes up the system. If this is indeed it, you should be able to just test it. The status is now disabled, put the system into sleep/hibernation and see if one of the USB devices (eg. mouse or keyboard) can turn the system back on, then change the setting and repeat and see if it now has changed.